# appengine python `PUT/DELETE` working on localhost but not in server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, restful-url

Why my application (appengine+python) `PUT/DELETE` working on localhost (response `status code 200`)  but not in server (appspot) (respone with `status code 0`)
[image]

Thanks.

app.yaml

```
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: guestbook.py
```

guestbook.py

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def put(self, id=None):
    self.response.out.write('put')
  def delete(self, id=None):
    self.response.out.write('delete')       
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>') 

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)


def main():
  wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

Comment: What application is that screenshot from? There is no "status code 0".

Comment: i'm using advanced rest client tool: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a browser issue! It works perfectly for me local/prod